# How can i parse XML file from internet using Jquery?

Tags: xml, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a trouble with an AJAX script, when i try to parse the XML file from internet, there's no response.
http://pastebin.com/hGe7siBB
I just want to parse a XML file from internet. 
PD: Gotta work for JQuery mobile.

Comment: You can't directly access the XML data of external site using Ajax (Cross Domain Ajax). You can use a proxy on the server side. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: Cross Origin Resource Sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely running into problems with the Same Origin Policy.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy